# How can i update variable in main process for multprocessing Manager in background process ...?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

Do you know how to sync my variable between client and updating my  variable in main process ?

- if you know how to trigger callback of function on client side when shared local_variable change ?

Shared python class :

```
import datetime
# Shared Class Methods

class Sharing():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.c = value

    def getLocalTime(self):
        return datetime.datetime.now()
    
    def getC(self):
        return self.c
    
    def setC(self, value):
        self.c = value
        print(self.c)
```

Server with background process

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
import shared as shared
import time



class MyManager(SyncManager): pass

# backgroud process sharing server
def start_bg_manager_server(local_variable):

    MyManager.register('share', local_variable.getC)
    manager = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'test')

    s = manager.get_server()

    s.serve_forever()



# init
if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_variable = shared.Sharing(20)

    p = Process(target=start_bg_manager_server, args=(local_variable,))
    p.start()

    print("DONE")

    while True:
        local_variable.setC(local_variable.getC() + 10)
        time.sleep(2)
```

```
e c:/Users/dev/Documents/poc_python/server.py
DONE
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
```

Here is a simple client consumer :

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

class MyManager(SyncManager): pass

MyManager.register('share')
m = MyManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey=b'test')
m.connect()
# print(m.share().setC(20))
print((m.share()))
```

```
PS C:\Users\dev\Documents\poc_python> python3 .\client.py
20
```

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

i do this with generative tool, it works and maybe it will help someone, but no callback for the moment :

```
import json
import multiprocessing.shared_memory as shm
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

def write_dict_to_shared_memory(data_dict):
    try:
        shared_str = shm.SharedMemory(size=1000, create=True, name='test')
    except:
        shared_str = shm.SharedMemory(create=False, name='test')
    # Convertir le dictionnaire en une chaîne JSON
    json_string = json.dumps(data_dict)
    # Convertir la chaîne JSON en bytes pour le stockage en mémoire partagée
    json_bytes = json_string.encode('utf-8')
    # S'assurer que la mémoire partagée a suffisamment de place pour stocker les données
    if shared_str.size < len(json_bytes):
        raise ValueError("La taille de la mémoire partagée est insuffisante.")
    # Écrire les données dans la mémoire partagée
    shared_str.buf[:len(json_bytes)] = json_bytes
    # Remplir le reste de la mémoire avec des caractères nuls pour effacer les anciennes données
    shared_str.buf[len(json_bytes):] = b'\x00' * (shared_str.size - len(json_bytes))

def read_dict_from_shared_memory():
    shared_str = shm.SharedMemory(create=False, name='test')
    # Lire les données depuis la mémoire partagée en bytes
    json_bytes = bytes(shared_str.buf[:])
    # Supprimer les caractères nuls de la chaîne
    json_cleaned = json_bytes.replace(b'\x00', b'')
    # Convertir les bytes en une chaîne JSON
    json_string = json_cleaned.decode('utf-8')
    # Charger le JSON pour obtenir le dictionnaire d'origine
    data_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    return data_dict

class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Dictionnaire à partager
    my_dict = {
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": 30,
        "City": "New York"
    }

    # Écrire le dictionnaire dans la mémoire partagée
    write_dict_to_shared_memory(my_dict)

    address = "my_pipe"
    MyManager.register('write_dict', write_dict_to_shared_memory)
    MyManager.register('read_dict', read_dict_from_shared_memory)

    # Créer le gestionnaire et le serveur
    manager = MyManager(address=address, authkey=b'secret')
    manager.get_server().serve_forever()
```

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

# Définir un gestionnaire personnalisé
class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Définir l'adresse et le port pour le gestionnaire (même que celui du serveur)
    address = "my_pipe"

    # Créer le gestionnaire et se connecter au serveur
    MyManager.register('write_dict')
    MyManager.register('read_dict')
    manager = MyManager(address=address, authkey=b'secret')
    manager.connect()

    # Obtenir les proxys des fonctions exposées
    # write_proxy = manager.write_dict
    read_proxy = manager.read_dict

    # Utiliser les fonctions pour accéder à la mémoire partagée
    shared_dict = read_proxy()
    print("Dictionnaire lu depuis la mémoire partagée:")
    print(shared_dict)
```